# Façade on Windows 7

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, facade

I downloaded Façade from the official site. But it seems it doesn't work properly on Windows 7.

How can I run it seamlessly on Windows 7 (32-bit)?

Problem: They stop talking at the beginning of the game. They don't respond anything. Game stuck there. I can move, walk but Grace and Trip don't respond anything.

Maybe it's not about Windows 7. Maybe it's game's bug or something. I googled and see other people who encounter this problem, but I cannot find any solution.

Comment: Did you try running it in compatability mode?

Comment: Define "stucks".

Comment: Yes I tried all compatability options.

Comment: Have you tried explaining your problem thoroughly?

Comment: Do you have Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate? Did the game use to work on Windows XP? When was it made / what OS(es) did it actually target?

Comment: @kotekzot I edited and tried to explain.

Comment: @Rick Win7 Ultimate

Comment: Does it always get stuck at a particular point in time? I've played for about 7 minutes (If you can call it that), and everything seemed to progress fine on Win 7 x64. Did you download FacadeInstaller1.1b3.exe?

Comment: Yes It always get stuck. Generally when I enter room and talk a few times. Then they stop talking and don't respond me. Yes I downloaded FacadeInstaller1.1b3.exe.

Comment: Maybe it's not about Windows 7. Maybe it's game's bug or something. I googled and see another people who encounter this problem. But I cannot find any solution.

Comment: If the compatability does not work then all I can think of is reinstalling the game. I myself have gotten it to work on win7 64-bit ultimate with winXP (SP3) compatability.